# How to install Android wear app onto android marshmallow avd emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, google-play, wear-os, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-virtual-device

For the last few days, I've been trying to get the android wear app working on an android marshmallow (API 23) emulator. The reason I'd like to do this, is so that I can pair my android (phone) emulator, with my android wear emulator, with a view to get an automated calabash smoke test running on jenkins. I know this is possible (or at least has been possible previously), as I found this (kennethmascarenhas.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/developing-for-android-wear-with-emulators/), which outlines pairing the two emulators together.

**What I've tried thus far:**

---

*(1) Install Android wear app onto marshmallow emulator running Google APIs*

Emulator config:

- Device: Nexus 5
- Target: Android 6.0 - API Level 23
- CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
- Emulator Options: Use Host GPU

Start up emulator:

```
emulator -avd <my_avd> -writable-system -no-boot-anim
```

Install the android wear app (downloaded from here: www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-wear/android-wear-1-5-0-2714488-gms-release/android-wear-1-5-0-2714488-gms-android-apk-download/):

```
adb -s emulator-5554 install <path_to_downloaded_wear_apk>
```

Opening the wear app however, produces a dialog stating: "Update your Google app on the Play Store. Then open Android Wear again."

This is where I went down the rabbit hole trying to get Google Play installed -_-

Interestingly, if you run the emulator with "Google APIs", the following google play apps are already bundled:

- Google play services - package:/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk=com.google.android.gms
  versionName=8.4.89 (2428711-470)
- Google Account Manager - package:/system/priv-app/GoogleLoginService/GoogleLoginService.apk=com.google.android.gsf.login
  versionName=6.0-2780065
- Google Services Framework - package:/system/priv-app/GoogleServicesFramework/GoogleServicesFramework.apk=com.google.android.gsf
  versionName=6.0-2780065
- Google Play Store - package:/system/app/LicenseChecker/LicenseChecker.apk=com.android.vending
  versionName=1.8 (Don't think this is actually it as I can't see app in apps list)

According to this blog post (www.flinkd.org/2015/02/installing-google-play-on-the-android-emulator-api-21-lollipop/), it is possible to install google play store (and everything that goes with it), or at least it was on API 21.

Remount emulator device partition to read-write:

```
adb remount
```

However, when I try to 'push' the apks to the emulator, e.g.:

```
adb push PrebuiltGmsCore.apk /system/priv-app
```

I get an error like:

```
failed to copy 'PrebuiltGmsCore.apk' to '/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk': Read-only file system
```

At this point, I decided to try something else.

---

*(2) Install google play store on marshmallow emulator NOT running Google APIs*

Emulator config:

- Device: Nexus 5
- Target: Android 6.0 - API Level 23
- CPU/ABI: Intel Atom (x86)
- Emulator Options: Use Host GPU

But again, I get the same 'Read-only file system' error as before when trying to 'push' the apks onto the device.

I even tried just installing them as you normally would, e.g.:

```
adb install <path_to_apk>
```

Which works, but appears to install the apps into the wrong directory with the wrong permissions. So when I open the Google Play Store app, I get a million errors saying google play services, framework and store have crashed (logcat saying "You need MANAGE_USERS permission" for each of the apps).

---

*(3) Other things I've tried*

Rather than running 'adb remount', I have also tried:

```
adb shell
su
mount -o rw,remount /system/priv-app/
```

But I get the same 'Read-only file system' error, when trying to 'push' the apks.

I've also tried your bog standard 'chmod' or /system/priv-app/, but again, I get the 'Read-only file system' error.

Oh, and also, before you ask, yes I'm running 'adb root'.

---

Has anyone out there had any luck with what I'm trying to accomplish? Please help.

P.S. Sorry about not having proper links. I don't have enough stack cred yet...

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I managed to figure it out myself - without having to install the Google Play Store app.

Using a marshmallow emulator (with Google APIs), I tried installing older versions of the Android wear app (downloaded from here http://www.apkmirror.com/?s=android+wear&post_type=app_release&searchtype=apk), until I could launch the app without getting the dialog prompting me to "Update your Google app on the Play Store. Then open Android Wear again.".

The lastest version that worked for me was:

Android Wear 1.4.0.2470307.gms (www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-wear/android-wear-1-4-0-2470307-gms-release/android-wear-1-4-0-2470307-gms-android-apk-download/)

In hindsight, I probably should have tried this approach first!

Once I had both emulators up and running, I ran:

```
adb -s <phone_emulator_name> forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
```

Looks like 5601 is a dedicated wearables port (see http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html)

Then I launched the android wear app, and selected 'Emulator' from the top left option spinner, and Huzzah!

Comment: Same problem here. Tried to connect a virtual Galaxy Nexus with Android 6.0 (Google API's 23) with a virtual Android Wear Watch Android 5.1 (API Level 22) without luck. I needed to install Android Wear 1.4.0.2470307.gms  on virtual handheld device and disconnect/reconnect Android Wear companion app a few times to make it work. Now the virtual phone does connect to smartwatch but my app communications between the two doesn't, while the same app tested on virtual handheld with API Level < 23 does. I'm using the suggested "GoogleApiClient" way and onDataChanged() on the watch never raises...